# Meteor JS alethes_pages.js:601 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Error: alethes_pages.js:601 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

I am new to Meteor Js. I am getting above mentioned error while implementing alethes-pages package.

I have implemented basic settings. Nothing fancy.

Following code is in 'both' folder.

```
Pages = new Meteor.Pagination('testCategory', {
    router: "iron-router",
    homeRoute: ["/", "/items/"],
    route: "/items/",
    routerTemplate: "War-id",
    routerLayout: "AdminLayout"
});


Pages.set({
    perPage: 10,
    sort: {
        category: -1
    }
});
```

Following is template:

```
    <template name="War-id">

This is War-id Template......

    {{> pages }}

  {{> pagesNav}}

</template>
```

The text is correctly displaying but pages template is not displayed

I have run command 'meteor update' in my working folder, so everything is on latest version as of (12/18/2014)

Can some one guide me what is going wrong and how it can be rectified.

Comment: could you please upload that code to http://meteorpad.com? or make some random box on Nitrous.io and it will be a pleasure help you

Comment: Where are your helpers defined?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor isn't very good with the character `-` in template names because of [javascript syntax rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Variables) with regard to variable names.

Use an underscore instead:

```
<template name="war_id">

</template>
```

Then use `Template.war_id.helpers` in your code instead of `Template.War-id.helpers` and also rename `routerTemplate: "War-id"` to `routerTemplate: "war_id"`

Comment: I also tried, even removed _,- and used Warid, but problem still exists.

Comment: The problem comes from a line of script in your code such as `Template.xx.helpers`, you have this line but you don't have the corresponding template for it. You've not mentioned the bit of code above but that would be the first place to look for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the order of how your define your package matters, inside my package.js, i put the common file I used to call new Meteor.Pagination last, so the depended Template(where I  call {{> pages}} ... could be loaded before Pages.coffee runs and it works :D

```
this.Pages = new Meteor.Pagination({
  templateName: "yourTemplateName",
  ...
});

api.add_files([
    'lib/common/pagination/common.js'
  ], ['client', 'server']);
```